# tricky logarithm substitutions, precalculus

Tags: logarithms

For all three, the second part in the ellipses is the question. For example, the first one would be

log base B (M) = X ... then ... log base M (B^2) = ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBn8B.gif

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASHol.gif

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIjUe.gif

throughly confused, an explanation would be very helpful

the capital / lowercase B is the same, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $B=b$ in the first problem

$x=\log_b(M) = \log(M)/\log(b)$,

$\log_M(B^2)= \log(B^2)/\log(M)=2 \log(B)/\log(M)=2/x$

second and third problems are very similar

Comment: thanks! I fully understand the first one but I am still confused for the second and third. the second one i got (log A) / (log B) = 2, (log A) / (log b^2) = ?

Comment: $\log(B^2)=2\log(B)$